# how to merge two big files according to some conditions?

Tags: algorithm, file

I have two files, their sizes are more than 1 TB. Every line is `id, name` in one file. Every line is `id, age` in other one. I want to merge them. Every lien of the result file is like `id, name, age`. Is there any good solution?

Comment: Are these files sorted by `id` field?

Comment: no，they are unordered

Comment: are the lines aligned to some common length or you have some directory structure with entry offsets or is this just CSV? are the lines whole in ASCII text or the numbers are binary? what is the (avg)length of line per each file and cca how many lines are there in each? may be a sample of the files (few lines from each) sharing will be a good idea. All this info can hint possible approach (dependent heavily on the table sizes) also how much RAM do you got at disposal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first - consider using databases - they are intended to make this sort of work perfectly.

If DB approach is not possible, prepare data files with sorting by `id` key.

There are some topics on sorting large files, external sorting - choose method suitable for you needs.

If possible, use *(I think - highly optimized)* utility like [GNU sort](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) that has possiibility to choose keys for comparison

Then perform merge operation - read lines from both sorted files, for equal id's form and write resulting string. If some `id` is less, read the next line from corresponding file and so on. Pseudocode:

```
 while not EOF(fileA) and  not EOF(fileB):
     if lineA.id == lineB.id:
          write(fileC, lineA.id, lineA.name, lineB.age)
          lineA = readNext(fileA)
          lineB = readNext(fileB)
     else if lineA.id < lineB.id:
          lineA = readNext(fileA)
     else:
          lineB = readNext(fileB)
```

Comment: @zhengkaiwang Be careful with this code sample. The loop will stop when either file reaches the end, meaning that the last id will be lost. You must have code after the loop that handles that case. Also, any id that doesn't exist in both files will be discarded.

Comment: @Jim Mischel  I assume that result is intersection, not union, so source lines without paired ones must be discarded.